# Edit JSON File in Scratch 3.0

Tags: json, mit-scratch

I would like to know if it is possible to edit the JSON file of Scratch 3.0 project. I downloaded a project, changed the name into a .zip, unzipping it, and opening the JSON file that it left. I did not change any line of the JSON code. I compressed the project and changed its name into sb3; but when I upload it the Scratch 3.0 GUI I got this:

Oops! Something went wrong.
We are so sorry, but it looks like Scratch has crashed. This bug has been automatically reported to the Scratch Team. Please refresh your page to try again.

Comment: In console:
Error: Failed to load project: Failed to unzip and extract project.json, with error: {}
    at e.value (lib.min.js:246)
    at i (lib.min.js:304)
    at beginWork (lib.min.js:304)
    at n (lib.min.js:304)
    at o (lib.min.js:304)
    at g (lib.min.js:304)
    at F (lib.min.js:304)
    at D (lib.min.js:304)
    at C (lib.min.js:304)
    at E (lib.min.js:304)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (lib.min.js:304)
    at e.C.setState (lib.min.js:312)
    at lib.min.js:246

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the folder structure of the new sb3 matches the original. If you zip the outer folder after extracting instead of the files inside, the folder structure won't be what Scratch expects and it will throw an error.

Comment: Yes, Exactly! I have solved the problem by zipping the files inside the folder and it works fine. Thank you anyway.